# How we can get Pre-Register / Unregister button on Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account

As we know Google launching new app called **Allo** and Pre-Registration of this app started on playstore.

Here I got surprised to see **Pre-Register** button instead **Install**.

I want to make my own **Pre-Register/Unregister** button on playstore for my app too.

I just saw recently same thing for [Allo App by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fireball&hl=en)

### Pre-Register:

[image]

### Unregister:

[image]

Is there any way to do this? How we can achieve this thing?

Your help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking us how to do this for your own app (as a developer)?

Comment: @Firelord Yeah.

Comment: @PratikButani you can find answer from [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37526639/624069)